# How to remove ?id= from my url website, using htaccess, i was read and try, but failed

Tags: .htaccess

My website like `https://example.com/?id=product`
help me to create htaccess so my url be
1. `https://www.example.com/product`

Thanks

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ product?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: So you want https://example.com/?id=product to **redirect** to https://example.com/product/ ? 301, 302?

Comment: yes, what can i do? and https://www.example.com/product

Answer (score 0):

Check this rule on the top of your .htaccess file. Change product.php to your product controller file.

In example https://www.example.com/any-product-name rewrite to https://www.example.com/product.php?id=any-product-name

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) /product.php?id=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```